# I am trying to hide the data and show it when it is clicked

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/css">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#mydiv').hide();
    $('.btn-group button').click(function(){
        var target = "#" + $(this).data("target");
        $("#mydiv").not(target).hide();
        $(target).show();
    });

});

</script>



<div class="btn-group">
     <tr>
         <td>
             <button><?php echo $request;?>
             </button>
         </td>
         <td>
             <div id="mydiv">
                  <?php echo $Time;?>
             </div>
         </td>
         <td>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock">
              </span>
         </td>
         <td>
              <?php echo $comments; ?>
         </td>
     </tr> 
<div>here
```

Comment: I am unable to show the data when i clicked the button can any one help please .

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/css">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#mydiv').hide();
    $('.btn-group button').click(function(){
        var target = "#" + $(this).attr("data-target");
        $("#mydiv").not(target).hide();
        $(target).show();
    });

});

</script>



<div class="btn-group">
     <tr>
         <td>
             <button data-target="mydiv"> BTN <?php echo $request;?>
             </button>
         </td>
         <td>
             <div id="mydiv">
                  <p>CONTENT OF MYDIV</p>
                  <?php echo $Time;?>
             </div>
         </td>
         <td>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock">
              </span>
         </td>
         <td>
              <?php echo $comments; ?>
         </td>
     </tr> 
<div>here
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/8wzjod0j/

Comment: `data-target`  not `target`

Comment: That makes more sense. :)

Comment: thanks but can any one tell me how could I display some hidden information when the component of that information is clicked . 
and that data that i want to to show is generic , i am fetching it from database and showing it . so how could I show its some content when it's name or some other content is clicked please help if someone can